# Magento 2, how to set default locale?

Tags: magento2, locale

In magento 2, how to set default locale? I default in admin page below:
[image]

I cleared all cache by command: `magento cache:flush`. But, it until get locale is `en_US`. If the true is `ja_JP`.

Comment: have you create .csv file inside ja_JP folder inside theme root folder

Comment: I did not create .csv file yet. How to create this file?

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create `ja_JP.csv` in your custom theme: `app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme name}/i18n/ja_JP.csv`

We can find the locale code by simple way:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the same my solution

Answer (score 1):

You have to create ja_JP.csv file in your custom theme.

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/i18n/ja_JP.csv

inside `ja_JP.csv` file first column is english name of text and other column name is japanese word.

example inside `ja_JP.csv` file.

```
"Add to compare","japanese word for add to compare set here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I hope this helps.

[image]

Credit to the owner of the thread: [Magento 2 - How do I change the locale of admin backend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113847/magento-2-how-do-i-change-the-locale-of-admin-backend)