# Magento 2 - How do I change the locale of admin backend?

Tags: magento2, backend, locale

I checked ALL the settings under stores->configuration. Is there a view mode or something else?

Comment: I switched to English US then it was possible to change the date.
I also switched JS off under Catalog/catalog date and time and use the format month/day/year

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can find Interface Locale from admin to upper right corner admin dropdown have menu **Account Setting**

[image]

Comment: I luv u :3 :3 :3

Answer (score 5):

Go to admin panel,click on,

**`This is for frontend Locale Changes,`**

> Stores -> Configuration -> General

Search Locale Options on that page.

You have to go for Locale Option in that page.

You can manage from here.

**`For adminpanel Locale Changes`**

Go to Admin panel,

Login with your usedid.

Now click on Top Right, Admin Link, Click on Admin Dropdown will open,

```
Click on Account Settings (admin)
```

New page with set your locale from dropdown field

> Interface Locale

save.

Comment: That changes the frontend locale :(

Comment: i have updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: And how can I change the default language behind the selected one? (the one where backend takes texts when it's not found in the CSV). Thanks