# How to set the locale (en_US") of Magento2 (I/F Locale) by using command line

Tags: magento2, locale, cli, command-line

I have installed magento 2.0.7 with CentoOS 7 / Apache 2.4.6 / PHP 7 / MariaDB 10. After applying the Japanese locale to "Interface Locale" under Account Setting (refer the link below), I get "HTTP ERROR 500" for accessing the admin console.

Link: [Magento 2 - How do I change the locale of admin backend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113847/magento-2-how-do-i-change-the-locale-of-admin-backend)

Found that the Japanese locale installation was incomplete. Consequently, I need a help for restoring the "en_US" locale by updating DB or Coding.

Please help me to resolve this issue by  providing the **steps to change the locale with using command line.**
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to find out the language code by using

```
php bin/magento info:language:list
```

Once you've found the language code you can set the language by calling

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --language=code
```

**UPD for v2.2**

```
magento config:set general/locale/code ${LOCALE}
```

or:

```
magento config:set general/locale/code ${LOCALE} --scope=store --scope-code=${STORE_CODE}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I found the lang code -> "| English (United States)          | en_US      |"

Unfortunately, I still get "HTTP ERROR 500" after "php... store-config:set  --language=en-US.  *Note that there no issue at the storefront locale. able to access.
Further help needed. Thank you

Comment: @kmoguls check your server error logs to see what the error is

Comment: Thanks for you continued support. I have executed uninstall command and reinstall it. I'm dropping the case. thank you.
Uninstall Command:
php bin/magento setup:uninstall

Comment: Is there any opportunity to set config for a particular store?

Comment: Yeah, found. It can be done by `magento config:set --scope=SCOPE --scope-code=SCOPE-CODE`.

Answer (score -1):

To expand on Raphael's answer, take a look at [Magento's DevDocs Configuring the store via command line](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-store.html)