# M2 - Change admin login language

Tags: magento2, backend, localisation, language, admin-login

does someone knows how to change magento's admin login language?

I have a language package installed (es_MX and pt_PT)

Things I've tried:

1) Changed admin user language in **Account Settings > Interface Locale** but it only translates when the admin user is logged in, but don't translates Admin login form.

2) Changed locale in **Stores > Configuration > Locale Options > Locale** but it is a configuration for frontend.

Any help is appreciated, maybe this is not something relevant for a login, but I don't want to brake user experience.

Comment: Please refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113847/magento-2-how-do-i-change-the-locale-of-admin-backend or https://community.magento.com/t5/Admin-Configuration-Questions/Change-Magento-2-CE-default-language/td-p/23634

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second try is in fact the right answer.

The setting in **Stores > Configuration > General > General > Locale Options > Locale** is responsible for the admin login form, but only when set for the **default scope**.

Once you use this setting in any "website" or "store view" scope, it will only apply to the frontend.