# Magento 2 - Translations in custom module

Tags: magento2, inline-translations

this is part of my

> etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
 <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
```

this is part of my file translations dictionary

> i18n/it_IT.csv

```
"General Configuration","Configurazioni generali"
```

> Store > Configuration > Local language > Italiano

but i cannot translate admin string in system configuration
[image]

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113847/magento-2-how-do-i-change-the-locale-of-admin-backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply user have english setting as local interface for admin. Change it to italiano and it works