# Magento 2: How to change text in admin panel?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, backend, language

how can I change the (German) labels in admin panel like in the screenhot for example?
I have tried to change this in "i18n" folders in custom theme and custom module but nothing worked.
For frontend it is working fine but I have no idea to change that for admin panel.
I have also cleaned all caches of corse.
Can anybody help please?

[image]

Comment: You changed account locale? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/113851/70343

Comment: Sure please read my comment below. The screenshot is only in english so that everybody can read it. Concrete I have put this in my csv file in i18n folder:

"Street Address","Straße / Haus-Nr."

Answer (score 1):

I think adding the translation with a language pack should do the trick + changing the language on the admin store to be the one you need.

Comment: There is already installed a language pack and of corse I do change the language in the admin panel. The screenshot is only in english so that can read everybody. But I want rename the translated text.

Answer (score 0):

Has nobody changed any text in the backend?