# Magento2 : Multi language store with diffrent url

Tags: magento2, multistore

I am trying to create multiple store for multiple language.
like

```
www.domain.com/no
wwww.domain.com/en
```

But I am unable to create these type URLs. With basic step of Magento store creation. Please help me with working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add the store code to Urls : **STORES > Configuration > General > Web > Url Options > Add Store Code to Urls**

[image]

Comment: In this case, the store code should the same language code.

Comment: yes. but when i trying to create diffrent website with diffrent code and diffrent store, then langauge swticher disable from front end

Comment: Khoa TruongDinh@ nay help regarding this

Comment: Let's me check again.

Comment: Khoa TruongDinh@ when i create store with different root  category then my  front end switcher is disable, even it's not working with different website code with different store . any better way to create store ,please help me this

Comment: Tomorrow, I will give you the final solution.

Comment: Khoa TruongDinh@@ let me know , if i create  different store with different category then how can i show  store switcher on home page

Comment: @SanjayYadav The store switcher is available in case the website has the store with multi store views. How you create the Website, Store and Store view structure?

Comment: ok thanks for this , please can you help me language translation, i have create  two store one is franch and one is English , but when i switch on franch this is not showing in franch ,

Comment: You need to config the language for your store: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/112857/33057

Comment: ok bro thanks for wonderful support,  Mr. bro can i ask one thing more,

Comment: Yes, sure. You can ask here Or you can create a new question in SE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50429/discussion-between-sanjay-yadav-and-khoa-truongdinh).